# How can I show specific gene names on the legend in a ggscatter plot in R using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, ggpubr

Create the specific point legend with scatter plot

Hi All,
I am using ggscatter to make a scatter plot. I was able to create the plot legend, but I don't know how to show specific gene names on the legend or how to change the different positions of the legends.

```
ggscatter(data_frame_merge, x = "log10TPM", y = "logFC", color = "Group", palette = c("#00AFBB", "#BBBBBB", "#FC4E07"), title = "M0 vs TAMEM_9")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), legend.position="right")+ 
  xlab(bquote(log[10](TPM)))+ 
  ylab(bquote(log[2](FC)))+ 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,5))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-15,15),breaks = get_breaks(by = 2.5, from = -15))+
  coord_cartesian(expand = F)+
  rremove("ticks") + geom_point(data = data_frame_merge %>% filter(gene_name == "Hjurp"),color = "red",size = 3) +
  geom_point(data = data_frame_merge %>% filter(gene_name == "Cdc25c"), color = "blue",size = 3) +
  geom_point(data = data_frame_merge %>% filter(gene_name == "Vsig4"), color = "green", size = 3)

dput(head(data_frame_merge))
structure(list(X = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), gene_name = c("Gnai3", 
"Pbsn", "H19", "Scml2", "Apoh", "Narf"), M0_TPM = c(63.08, 0, 
0.24, 0.32, 0, 8.96), TAMEM = c(60.36, 0, 0.07, 1.14, 0, 16.6
), TAMEM_9_TPM = c(58.17, 0, 0.99, 0.02, 0, 15.83), TAMEM_C_5.x = c(71.45, 
0, 0.38, 0.4, 0.31, 9.63), M0 = c(3760, 0, 9, 6, 0, 737), TAMEM_9 = c(3213, 
0, 14, 2, 0, 1205), logFC = c(0.008986276, 0, 0.863500696, -1.300783986, 
0, 0.94496773), logCPM = c(7.036410655, -3.732344581, -0.965343021, 
-2.154956244, -3.732344581, 5.230839035), PValue = c(0.966983348, 
1, 0.235318227, 0.298737053, 1, 1.32e-05), Signifi = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), log10TPM = c(1.789756932, 0, 0.208172527, 0.068185862, 
0, 1.126942718), Group = c("noSig", "noSig", "noSig", "noSig", 
"noSig", "noSig")), row.names = c("ENSMUSG00000000001", "ENSMUSG00000000003", 
"ENSMUSG00000000031", "ENSMUSG00000000037", "ENSMUSG00000000049", 
"ENSMUSG00000000056"), class = "data.frame")
```

Current output

[Current Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMHzZ.png)
Lets say I want to show genenames "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene3" on the legend and there is the example plot below. How to make the similar legend like example plot.[Example Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xmKL.png)
Many thanks!

Example Figure Source: Mu R, Zhang Z, Han C, Niu Y, Xing Z, Liao Z, Xu J, Shao N, Chen G, Zhang J, Dong L, Wang C. Tumor-associated macrophages-educated reparative macrophages promote diabetic wound healing. EMBO Mol Med. 2023 Feb 8;15(2):e16671. doi: 10.15252/emmm.202216671. Epub 2022 Dec 21. PMID: 36541165; PMCID: PMC9906426.

Comment: Could you provide a little bit of your data. For example `dput(head(data_frame_merge))`

Comment: @TarJae Thank you for your reply. I already edited my code and uploaded the data description. My question is how to annotate the gene by the gene name I am interested in and show the legend on the plot. Thanks.